# Unable to find client side html date control from server side

Tags: html, asp.net

Unable to find client side html date control from server side.

Following html code is for capturing date.

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="dtpdob" runat="server" placeholder="Enter Date of Birth" name="dtpdob"  />
```

Following code in server side for finding the control of client side.

```
Dim btns As HtmlInputText = TryCast(Me.FindControl("dtpdob"), HtmlInputText)
If btns.Value = "" Then
   lblErrorText.Text = "No data available"
End If
```

System is giving the following error in btns.Value

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.' btns was Nothing.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following :

```
Dim btns As HtmlInputControl = DirectCast(Me.FindControl("dtpdob"), System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputControl)
    If btns.Value = "" Then
        lblErrorText.Text = "No data available"
    End If
```

Comment: Lot of Thanks. Its done.